# subprocess ignores bufsize argument

Tags: python, python-2.6

I was trying to run and process the stdout of some java program and found that my Python script was eternally waiting. Then I've wrote a new test script to test `subprocess` and found that, again, **I see no output when running this**:

```
$ cat test.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

c = ['/usr/bin/tail', '-f', '/var/log/dmesg']
proc = subprocess.Popen(c, 
                                     bufsize=1,
                                     shell=False, 
                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

for line in proc.stdout:
    print line
```

Why is `subprocess` ignoring my `bufsize` argument? Is there some intermediate buffering I'm missing to take into account? I expect to read the first 10 lines of `tail` and then eternally wait until new lines are appened to the `dmesg` file. My user do have permissions, running the command on `bash` gives output.

Changing `tail` to `yes` seems to fill some buffers and I can see lots of output.

Comment: does `for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):` work?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes!! Thanks, post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `iter(proc.stdout.readline,'')`:

```
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
   print line
```

`for line in proc.stdout` reads all the input before iterating over the content.